# Use eslint-plugin-compat alongside Babel

Tags: javascript, webpack, cross-browser, babeljs, eslint

I have a webpack project that uses Babel for JavaScript transpilation. To tell Babel which browsers to target when it transpiles my code, I use a `.browserslistrc` file.

I'm also interested in using the ESLint compatibility plugin, `eslint-plugin-compat`, which will warn you if you're using JS that is not compatible with the browsers you are targeting (the ESLint plugin also refers to the `.browserslistrc` file).

So I went ahead and installed and added the plugin to my `.eslintrc.js` file, and it seems to be working fine. But when I compile my webpack project, ESLint is pointing out features I'm using in my code, like `Object.values()`, that are not compatible with my target browsers. Well yeah, I know that - that's why I'm using Babel, so those features are converted to ones that are compatible for the browsers I'm targeting.

So maybe I'm missing a key point here somewhere. If I'm using Babel already to transpile to compatible code in the browsers I'm targeting, is there still any use for `eslint-plugin-compat` in my build process?

Comment: The solution for this (at the moment) is to manually polyfill APIs (see the README). Proper support for this is being discussed in https://github.com/amilajack/eslint-plugin-compat/issues/174.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rather use [`babel-eslint`](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint), which

> allows you to lint ALL valid Babel code with the fantastic ESLint.

I am just planning to make this change, so I don't have any experience with it, but should mean that it makes `eslint-plugin-compat` unnecessary, as no "invalid" code should go to the bundle.

But on the other hand, still there *are* useful hints from `eslint-plugin-compat`, like `window.screenLeft() is not supported in Firefox XY`. Disqualifying `eslint-plugin-compat` would also skip these hints in my opinion.

**Update** You can track this on https://github.com/amilajack/eslint-plugin-compat/issues/174